# What kind of car does Derek Hale drive in Teen Wolf?

Tags: teen-wolf

I want to know what kind of car Derek Hale drives in *Teen Wolf*. I know it is between a Camaro and a Challenger but I am not sure. If you answer the question make sure there is a lot of evidence because I want to be sure. I am talking about the car he drives in season 1.

Comment: “If you answer the question make sure there is a lot of evidence because I want to be sure.” — It’s a car, not a murder-mystery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from this image it's a Chevrolet Camaro (hint: see the Chevy emblem on the grill).

[image: Gif showing a camera panning across a black Camaro pulled up at a petrol station with a man filling it up]

Comment: I didn't see the chevrolet symbol, and in the script to the pilot they said it was a Dodge challenger.

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock You can see the symbol on the grill. its the cross shape.

Comment: I saw the symbol now, that's why this is the best answer for me. I was just commenting that the pilot script was inaccurate and fan reviews were mixed.

Answer (score 1):

It can range from 2010, 2011, or 2012 Chevy Camaro give or take, likely with a black leather interior. The Chevy bowtie and albeit very tiny 'Camaro' on the front driver side should also clue into this.

I've done extensive research over Camaros like this, and as TV Shows tend to use cars from the current year, or the future year, I would definitely say it is likely a 2011 or 2012 Chevy Camaro.

Take the FJ Cruiser in Season 3B onward, it's model year is 2014, which is roughly when that half of the season came on to the TV.

Answer (score 0):

It's a black Chevy Camaro from 2009. It's my favorite car, that's how I know.

[image: Front view of a black Camaro driving down a road with its lights on]

Comment: I don't know know anything about cars, so please provide a different image if that one is incorrect

Answer (score -1):

It’s a Camaro because my dad has a Camaro and it looks very alike but his is blue. Plus my dad also says it’s a Camaro and he knows his cars because used to work as a mechanic.

Comment: Can you provide any confirmation that it is indeed a Camaro, and what type of Camaro it may be?

Answer (score -3):

It is obviously a Ford Mustang if you compare it to other Ford Mustangs

Comment: I guess you didn't notice the Chevy symbol in the image included in the other answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SCIFI&FA SE. Please refrain from using answers to add details or ask for ones. Use the commentaries section below answers and questions to do that. Feel free to have the tour to show you around this amazing community. Cheers!